# Fastest way to test for array inclusion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, benchmarking

I was wondering. What is the fastest way to test if an array contains another in Ruby? So I build this little benchmark script. Would love to hear your thoughts on comparison methods. Do you know some other - perhaps even better way to do it?

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

a = ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle
b = ["b","d","f"]

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
      10000.times do
          Set[b].subset?(a.to_set)
      end
  end
  x.report do
      10000.times do
          (a & b).count == b.size
      end
  end
    x.report do
      10000.times do
          (a.inject(0) {|s,i| s += b.include?(i)?1:0 } == b.size)
      end
    end
    x.report do
      10000.times do
          (b - a).empty?
      end
    end
    x.report do
      10000.times do
          b.all? { |o| a.include? o }
      end
    end
end
```

And results:

```
     user     system      total        real
 0.380000   0.010000   0.390000 (  0.404371)
 0.050000   0.010000   0.060000 (  0.075062)
 0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.140420)
 0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.136385)
 0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.034405)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare?  That they have the same size or the same elements?  Why not just do a == b?

Comment: It looks like he just wants to know that b is a subset of a.

Comment: You should run each part many times (i.e., wrap each in `10000.times do ... end`) and/or use larger arrays in order to get more meaningful results.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I changed code. Now there is bigger initial array and some loops... Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First, be very careful about micro benchmarking. I recommend using my gem [`fruity`](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) for that, see the docs as to why.

Second, do you want to compare the creation of your arrays plus the comparison, or just the comparison?

Third, your data is so small you won't be able to understand what is going on. For example, your `b` variable holds 3 elements. If you compare an algorithm in `O(n^2)` to one in `O(n)`, with such a small `n` (3) it won't be obvious.

You may want to start from:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

a = ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle
b = %w[b d f]
a_set = a.to_set
b_set = b.to_set

compare do
  subset        { b_set.subset?(a_set) }
  intersect     { (a & b).size == b.size }
  subtract      { (b - a).empty? }
  array_include { b.all?{|o| a.include? o} }
  set_include   { b.all?{|o| a_set.include? o} }
end
```

Gives:

```
Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
set_include is faster than subset by 1.9x ± 0.1
subset is faster than intersect by 60% ± 10.0%
intersect is faster than array_include by 40% ± 1.0%
array_include is faster than subtract by 1.9x ± 0.1
```

Note that `Array#&` and `Array#-` will basically convert on of the argument to a `Set` internally. The `all?` and `include?` on the array should be the worst solution, because it will be `O(n^2)`... this would be apparent if you increase the size of `b`.

The general answer is: use the most legible unless you know for sure you need to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data size. For a small data set as you have; `b.all? { |o| a.include? o }` is quicker almost every time.

However, if you try with larger arrays. E.g. arrays of 1000 elements, `(a & b) == b.size` is considerably faster.

I also tried the opposite version: `(a | b) == a.size`, which was more or less the same.

Here are the (commented) results where `a` has 10000 elements and `b` has 5000 elements:

```
    user     system      total        real
0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.004445) # subset
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003073) # & (intersection)
1.620000   0.000000   1.620000 (  1.625472) # inject
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004485) # difference
0.530000   0.000000   0.530000 (  0.529042) # include
0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.004416) # | (union)
```